# find $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^{k-1}}{n^k-\left(n-1\right)^k}\right)=\frac{1}{2005}$ the value of k

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^{k-1}}{n^k-\left(n-1\right)^k}\right)=\frac{1}{2005}$

What is the value of k in the given expression?

When I expand the term (n-1) to the k-th power I get n^k-n^k..

Comment: Instead of $x\to\infty$ you mean $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor expansions, assuming $k \geq 1$ (so that things do tend to $\infty$ when $n\to\infty$):
$$\begin{align}
n^k - (n-1)^k &= n^k\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\right) = n^k\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right) \\&= kn^{k-1} + o\left(n^{k-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

so
$$
\frac{n^{k-1}}{n^k - (n-1)^k} = \frac{n^{k-1}}{kn^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1})} = \frac{1}{k+o(1)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{k}
$$
and you can conclude by unicity of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^{k-1}}{n^k-\left(n-1\right)^k}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k}\right)$$
the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$, so you can use the L'hopital Rule
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{n^2}}{-k\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-1}(\frac{1}{n^2})}\right)=\frac{1}{k}$$
so the $k$
$$k={2005}$$